# ¿Cómo ubicar correctamente botones usando position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando hacer el `index` de un sitio como se muestra acá

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo problemas con la ubicación de los botones, intento hacer que se vean iguales en distintas resoluciones utilizando como estilo propiedades como esta para cada botón

```
#b_estrategic{    
   left:25%;
   top: 30%;
   padding-right: 30px;
   text-align: right;
}
```

Pero para cuando pruebo el sitio con otras resoluciones los botones se ven corridos, cómo puedo hacer para que aparezcan siempre en el mismo lugar? Ya probé usando valores en píxeles.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir trabajando con los **Media Queries** donde indiques según la resolución la posición de tus elementos ejemplo:

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper_cuadros{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro1,
.cuadro2,
.cuadro3,
.cuadro4{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 50px;
}

.cuadro1{
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}

.cuadro2{
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
}

.cuadro3{
  bottom: 0px;
  left:0px;
}

.cuadro4{
  bottom: 0px;
  right:0px;
}

.cuadro5{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
  width: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  
  .cuadro1{
    border:1px solid green;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
  }

  .cuadro2{
    border:1px solid yellow;
    right:50px;
    top:50px;
  }

  .cuadro3{
    border:1px solid orange;
    bottom: 50px;
    left:50px;
  }

  .cuadro4{
    border:1px solid black;
    bottom: 50px;
    right:50px;
  }
  
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  
  .cuadro1{
    border:1px solid green;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
  }

  .cuadro2{
    border:1px solid yellow;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
  }

  .cuadro3{
    border:1px solid orange;
    bottom: 20px;
    left:20px;
  }

  .cuadro4{
    border:1px solid black;
    bottom: 20px;
    right:20px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper_cuadros">
    <div class="cuadro1">1</div>
    <div class="cuadro2">2</div>
    <div class="cuadro3">3</div>
    <div class="cuadro4">4</div>
    <div class="cuadro5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como veras coloque dos **Media Queries** para que fueran cambiando de posición y color, cuando ejecutes este código en la parte inferior derecha tienes la opción de verlo pantalla completa y trata luego de ir reduciendo el ancho de la venta ay veras como funciona.

Puedes customizar los **Media Queries** para lo que quieras ejemplo:

```
/* En pantallas con 992px o menos, configure el color de fondo en azul */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

/* En pantallas de 600 px o menos, configure el color de fondo a verde oliva */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

Los **Media Queries** se pueden utilizar para verificar muchas cosas, como:

```
- ancho y alto de la ventana
- ancho y alto del dispositivo
- orientación (¿la tableta / teléfono está en modo horizontal o vertical?)
- resolución
```

Espero que sea lo que estas buscando.